# Is there a doc that shows the complete state transitions for all possible steps in aws step functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I want to some processing on the results of the `getExecutionHistory()` api of AWS StepFunctions. Per the doc on this api https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.get_execution_history each event in the events array has a type which is a one of a very large enum:

```
'type': 'ActivityFailed'|'ActivityScheduled'|'ActivityScheduleFailed'|'ActivityStarted'|'ActivitySucceeded'|'ActivityTimedOut'|'ChoiceStateEntered'|'ChoiceStateExited'|'ExecutionAborted'|'ExecutionFailed'|'ExecutionStarted'|'ExecutionSucceeded'|'ExecutionTimedOut'|'FailStateEntered'|'LambdaFunctionFailed'|'LambdaFunctionScheduled'|'LambdaFunctionScheduleFailed'|'LambdaFunctionStarted'|'LambdaFunctionStartFailed'|'LambdaFunctionSucceeded'|'LambdaFunctionTimedOut'|'MapIterationAborted'|'MapIterationFailed'|'MapIterationStarted'|'MapIterationSucceeded'|'MapStateAborted'|'MapStateEntered'|'MapStateExited'|'MapStateFailed'|'MapStateStarted'|'MapStateSucceeded'|'ParallelStateAborted'|'ParallelStateEntered'|'ParallelStateExited'|'ParallelStateFailed'|'ParallelStateStarted'|'ParallelStateSucceeded'|'PassStateEntered'|'PassStateExited'|'SucceedStateEntered'|'SucceedStateExited'|'TaskFailed'|'TaskScheduled'|'TaskStarted'|'TaskStartFailed'|'TaskStateAborted'|'TaskStateEntered'|'TaskStateExited'|'TaskSubmitFailed'|'TaskSubmitted'|'TaskSucceeded'|'TaskTimedOut'|'WaitStateAborted'|'WaitStateEntered'|'WaitStateExited',
```

I want to match start and end states with each other. For example, "ActivityScheduled" if there's a failure will match with "ActivityScheduleFailed". ActivityStarted should match with one of ActivitySucceeded or ActivityFailed.

To determine these matches, I need to see a complete state transition diagram. I've run some executions and called the api and am observing the response, and i can see some patterns like scheduling always happens before starting, but before I make any assumptions I want to validate that with some doc.